# ClassNotFoundException thrown by RecommenderJob (Apache Mahout on Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, classnotfoundexception, mahout

I am using the org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.pseudo.RecommenderJob.java file to run a pseudo distributed recommender. I am using it to run the GenericItemsRecommender class.

The command I am using is

> bin/hadoop jar mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT-job org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.pesudo.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=./ratingsLess.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=/input/output --tempDir /input/tmp --recommenderClassName org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericItemBasedRecommender

When I run it I get an Exception saying :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.pesudo.RecommenderJob
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)

Could you please let me know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Solved. Package was named incorrectly.